sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Application.initialize' was never awaited
I read transition guide for python-telegram-bot here and here but I can't fix correctly my code
I installed last PTB version (21.1.1) but I wrong something, it appears that the __run method of the Application class is trying to close the event loop, but the loop is still running and the Application.shutdown coroutine was called but was not waited for with wait
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/bot.py", line 51, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 654, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/bot.py", line 46, in main
    await application.run_polling()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/ext/_application.py", line 838, in run_polling
    return self.__run(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/ext/_application.py", line 1065, in __run
    loop.close()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 68, in close
    super().close()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 88, in close
    raise RuntimeError("Cannot close a running event loop")
RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Application.shutdown' was never awaited
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Application.initialize' was never awaited

I test with this code but my bot doesn't start using /start command
import os
import asyncio
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, Update
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, MessageHandler, filters, CallbackContext
import requests

TOKEN = os.getenv("TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN")
PORT = int(os.environ.get('PORT', '8443'))

async def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    await update.message.reply_text('Inserisci il titolo che vuoi cercare:')

async def echo(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    titolo = update.message.text
    tabelle = ["film", "anime", "serietv"]
    risultati = []
    for tabella in tabelle:
        url = f"https://ilxxxx.com/api?table={tabella}&page=1&filtro={titolo}"
        response = await requests.get(url)
        data = response.json()
        for item in data['items']:
            risultati.append(item)

    if risultati:
        keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton(f"{i+1}. {item['titolo']}", callback_data=str(i)) for i, item in enumerate(risultati)]]
        reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
        await update.message.reply_text('Seleziona un risultato:', reply_markup=reply_markup)
    else:
        await update.message.reply_text('Nessun risultato trovato.')

async def button(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    query = update.callback_query
    await query.answer()
    risultati = context.user_data['risultati']
    scelto = risultati[int(query.data)]
    await query.edit_message_text(text=f"Magnet: {scelto['magnet']}")

async def main() -> None:
    update_queue = asyncio.Queue()
    application = ApplicationBuilder().token(TOKEN).update_queue(update_queue).build()

    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    application.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, echo))
    application.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))

    await application.run_polling()

    await application.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Any idea to fix ?

The code posted doesn't match the code run in at least one place -> the code is just calling main(), while the actual code run uses the correct call asyncio.run(main()). Are there any other differences?
